# Closing stdout or stdin

Tags: rust

Since files and streams are closed automatically when being dropped, but `io::stdin()` only providing a handle to the underlying stream, I fail to see how to explicitly close `stdin` or `stdout` or detect EOF on `stdin` in my program.

Consider

```
fn main() {
    let mut stdin = io::stdin();
    let mut linebuffer = String::new();
    loop {
        match stdin.read_line(&mut linebuffer) {
            Ok(i) if i == 0 => { break; },
            Ok(i) => {
                println!("{} {}", linebuffer, i);
            },
            Err(e) => { panic!(e); }
        }
        linebuffer.clear();
    }
}
```

Checking the number of bytes put into the buffer seems flaky because the pipe might get flushed with zero bytes having being written to it. Reading from a closed `stdin` should cause an `IOError`, but it doesn't.

Somewhat related to that: How to explicitly close my own `stdout` / `stderr`?

Comment: Please ask only [one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts). This should either be about detecting EOF or how to close `stdin` / `stdout`, but not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago there was `ErrorKind::EndOfFile` enum variant which was emitted upon a read operation when the source stream is closed. It seems that it didn't get to the new I/O library implementation, and instead `Read` trait has been changed to return 0 read bytes upon EOF. And indeed, this is [specified](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0517-io-os-reform.md#errors) in I/O reform RFC. So yes, checking for zero is a valid way to detect end of stream in the current Rust.

By the way, you can write `Ok(0)` instead of `Ok(i) if i == 0`:

```rust
match stdin.read_line(&mut buf) {
    Ok(0) => break,
    ...
}
```

As for how to close `stdout()`/`stderr()`, it seems that the current API does not provide a way to do it, unfortunately. It is probably a feature worth an RFC or at least an RFC issue.

Comment: Is there a way to close the stdin/out now?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding my own sub-question on how to close stdout/stderr: The correct way is to use the [wait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait)- or the [wait_with_output](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait_with_output)-method on a `process::Child`. Both methods close the subprocess's stdin before waiting for it to quit, eliminating the possibility of a deadlock between both processes.

Comment: Actually, you close it by doing the following: `drop(child.stdin.take());`

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs for both [`ChildStdin`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ChildStdin.html) and [`ChildStdout`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.ChildStdout.html), they are closed when they are [dropped](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html).

Here’s an example that closes stdin:

```rust
use std::io::Write;
use std::process::{Command, Stdio};

fn main() {
    let mut child = Command::new("cat")
        .stdin(Stdio::piped())
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .spawn()
        .unwrap();

    let mut stdin = child.stdin.take().unwrap();
    stdin.write("Hello, world!\n".as_bytes()).unwrap();
    drop(stdin);

    let output = child.wait_with_output().unwrap();
    let stdout = String::from_utf8(output.stdout).unwrap();

    print!("{}", stdout);
}
```